# Combining the data of a query into one single row based on a condition

Tags: mysql, case

I have the data in the following manner

```
code1  code2  new_status  created_at   old_status
A       1        S2        x            S1
A       1        S3        y            s2
A       1        S4        z            S3
B       2        S3        P            S1
```

I want the data in the following manner after querying

```
code1   code2   S1   S1_date  S2   S2_date   s3   s3_date   s4    s4_date
A        1       0      0      1    x         1     y        1        z
B        2       0      0      0    0         1     P        0        0
```

I am currently using case to dufferentiate between the status but getting different rows for each status. I want it combined as shown above.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good idea to implement this within MySQL because MySQL doesn't support PIVOT as per my knowledge.

But still, you can use the below SQL to get your desired result in MySQL only.

SQL:

```
select code1,code2,
       max(case when new_status='S1' then 1 else 0 end) S1,
       max(case when new_status='S1' then created_dt else 0 end) S1_date,
       max(case when new_status='S2' then 1 else 0 end) S2,
       max(case when new_status='S2' then created_dt else 0 end) S2_date,
       max(case when new_status='S3' then 1 else 0 end) S3,
       max(case when new_status='S3' then created_dt else 0 end) S3_date,
       max(case when new_status='S4' then 1 else 0 end) S4,
       max(case when new_status='S4' then created_dt else 0 end) S4_date
from xyz
group by code1,code2;
```

## Example from your sample data to Output:

```
mysql> create table xyz(code1 varchar(20),code2 varchar(20),new_status varchar(20),created_dt varchar(20),old_status varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.46 sec)

mysql> insert into xyz values
    -> ('A','1','S2','x','S1'),
    -> ('A','1','S3','y','s2'),
    -> ('A','1','S4','z','S3'),
    -> ('B','2','S3','P','S1');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> select code1,code2,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S1' then 1 else 0 end) S1,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S1' then created_dt else 0 end) S1_date,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S2' then 1 else 0 end) S2,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S2' then created_dt else 0 end) S2_date,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S3' then 1 else 0 end) S3,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S3' then created_dt else 0 end) S3_date,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S4' then 1 else 0 end) S4,
    ->        max(case when new_status='S4' then created_dt else 0 end) S4_date
    -> from xyz
    -> group by code1,code2;
+-------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+
| code1 | code2 | S1   | S1_date | S2   | S2_date | S3   | S3_date | S4   | S4_date |
+-------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+
| A     | 1     |    0 | 0       |    1 | x       |    1 | y       |    1 | z       |
| B     | 2     |    0 | 0       |    0 | 0       |    1 | P       |    0 | 0       |
+-------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So, basically you want to make single column out of "S2" and "S3", if any of both "S2" or "S3" has status then you want return into new column called "NEW_S", and if both are doesn't have then "0", is it?